# Why Wso2 identity custom user store is not loading. Getting ClassNotFoundException?

Tags: osgi-bundle, wso2-identity-server

I am developing a custom user store manager in wso2 identity. I have created a custom user store as osgi bundle and placed inside the dropins folder of wso2 server directory. When i restarting the server getting "ClassNotFoundException" here is my class,

```
   package com.xxx.identity.userstore.internal;

import com.xxx.identity.userstore.CustomUserStoreCoordinator;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.osgi.service.component.ComponentContext;
import org.wso2.carbon.user.api.UserStoreManager;

public class CustomUserStoreCoordinatorComponent {

    private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(CustomUserStoreCoordinatorComponent.class);

    public CustomUserStoreCoordinatorComponent(){

    }

    public void activate(ComponentContext ctxt) {

        CustomUserStoreCoordinator customUserStoreManager = new CustomUserStoreCoordinator();
        ctxt.getBundleContext().registerService(UserStoreManager.class.getName(), customUserStoreManager,  null);
        log.info("Custom User store co-ordinator bundle activated successfully..");
    }

    public void deactivate(ComponentContext ctxt) {
        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.info("Custom User store co-ordinator bundle successfully deactivated");
        }
    }

}
```

Here is my usr-mgt.xml

```
    <UserManager>
    <Realm>
        <Configuration>
        <AddAdmin>true</AddAdmin>
            <AdminRole>admin</AdminRole>
            <AdminUser>
                <UserName>admin</UserName>
                <Password>admin</Password>
            </AdminUser>
            <EveryOneRoleName>everyone</EveryOneRoleName> <!-- By default users in this role sees the registry root -->
            <Property name="isCascadeDeleteEnabled">true</Property>
            <Property name="dataSource">jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</Property>
        </Configuration>

        <!-- Following is the configuration for internal JDBC user store. This user store manager is based on JDBC.
             In case if application needs to manage passwords externally set property
             <Property name="PasswordsExternallyManaged">true</Property>.
             In case if user core cache domain is needed to identify uniquely set property
             <Property name="UserCoreCacheIdentifier">domain</Property>.
             Furthermore properties, IsEmailUserName and DomainCalculation are readonly properties.
             Note: Do not comment within UserStoreManager tags. Cause, specific tag names are used as tokens
             when building configurations for products.
        -->
        <UserStoreManager class="com.xxx.identity.userstore.CustomUserStoreCoordinator">
            <Property name="TenantManager">org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.JDBCTenantManager</Property>
            <Property name="ReadOnly">false</Property>
            <Property name="ReadGroups">true</Property>
            <Property name="WriteGroups">true</Property>
            <Property name="UsernameJavaRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="UsernameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="UsernameJavaRegExViolationErrorMsg">Username pattern policy violated</Property>
            <Property name="PasswordJavaRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="PasswordJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="PasswordJavaRegExViolationErrorMsg">Password length should be within 5 to 30 characters</Property>
            <Property name="RolenameJavaRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="RolenameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="CaseInsensitiveUsername">true</Property>
            <Property name="SCIMEnabled">false</Property>
            <Property name="IsBulkImportSupported">false</Property>
            <Property name="PasswordDigest">SHA-256</Property>
            <Property name="StoreSaltedPassword">true</Property>
            <Property name="MultiAttributeSeparator">,</Property>
            <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property>
            <Property name="MaxRoleNameListLength">100</Property>
            <Property name="UserRolesCacheEnabled">true</Property>
            <Property name="UserNameUniqueAcrossTenants">false</Property>
            <Property name="maxActive">50</Property>
            <Property name="maxWait">60000</Property>
            <Property name="minIdle">5</Property>
        </UserStoreManager>
        <AuthorizationManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager">
            <Property name="AdminRoleManagementPermissions">/permission</Property>
            <Property name="AuthorizationCacheEnabled">true</Property>
            <Property name="GetAllRolesOfUserEnabled">false</Property>
        </AuthorizationManager>
    </Realm>
</UserManager>
```

What I have missed out here ?

Comment: Can you please post you pom (Hope you are using maven to build) file and full stack trace of the exception.

Comment: You haven't provided the exception stack trace, nor have you provided the manifest for the bundle. This makes the question extremely difficult to answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My OSGI bundle deployed successfully now. The issue here is the dependencies are not packaged with the bundle and while deploying the bundle without those it throws different errors in the log but while debugging only found the issue and placed the dependencies in the right folder and now everything is working as expected.